# Make HttpLoggingInterceptor do not log images

Tags: android, kotlin, logging, retrofit, okhttp

I'm trying to get rid of trash in logs, like

> *�$ʞx���J/

when i recieve an image

So i tried to override HttpLoggingInterceptor intercept(), to detect is there a Content-Type => image/jpeg header in responce, but HttpLoggingInterceptor is final so i cant extend it :(

Code in RetrofitModule:

```
OkHttpClient provideOkHttpClient(Context context, Application app, Preferences preferences) {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        loggingInterceptor.setLevel(BuildConfig.DEBUG ? HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY : HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.HEADERS);

        Cache cache = new Cache(app.getCacheDir(), cacheSize);

        return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addNetworkInterceptor(new OkHttpInterceptor(context, preferences))
                .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
                .cache(cache)
                .build();
    }
```

How can i disable image-logging in my project?

Comment: Can't believe that all cool developers just ignore trash in logs :(

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So, since no one have an answer iv'e invent my own bicycle:

```
    HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor(new HttpLoggingInterceptor.Logger() {
        @Override
        public void log(String message) {
            if(!message.contains("�")){
                Timber.d(message);
            }
        }
    });
```

Not really sure if String.contains() cheap enough for use it like this, but goal is reached

Answer (score 4):

You can use `OkHttpLogger` class to print logs without binary data:

```
class OkHttpLogger : HttpLoggingInterceptor.Logger {
    override fun log(message: String) {
        okHttpLog(message)
    }

    private fun okHttpLog(message: String, level: Int = Log.DEBUG, t: Throwable? = null) {
        val maxLogLength = 4000
        val tag = "OkHttp"
        val encoder = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1").newEncoder()

        var logMessage = message
        if (t != null) logMessage = logMessage + '\n'.toString() + Log.getStackTraceString(t)

        // Split by line, then ensure each line can fit into Log's maximum length.
        var i = 0
        val length = logMessage.length
        var isBinaryLogDisplayed = false
        var isBinaryContentType = false
        while (i < length) {
            var newline = logMessage.indexOf('\n', i)
            newline = if (newline != -1) newline else length
            do {
                val end = minOf(newline, i + maxLogLength)
                val msg = logMessage.substring(i, end).trim()

                if (msg.contains("Content-Type") &&
                    msg.contains("application/octet-stream")) { // use another Content-Type if need
                    isBinaryContentType = true
                }
                val isBinaryData = !encoder.canEncode(msg)

                // multipart boundary
                if (isBinaryLogDisplayed && msg.startsWith("--")) {
                    isBinaryContentType = false
                    isBinaryLogDisplayed = false
                }

                // don't print binary data
                if (isBinaryContentType && isBinaryData && !isBinaryLogDisplayed) {
                    Log.println(level, tag, "<BINARY DATA>")
                    isBinaryLogDisplayed = true
                }

                if (!isBinaryLogDisplayed) {
                    Log.println(level, tag, msg)
                }

                i = end
            } while (i < newline)
            i++
        }
    }
}
```

To use it pass an instance to `HttpLoggingInterceptor`'s constructor:

```
val httpLoggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor(OkHttpLogger()).apply {
    level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
}
```